# component method didnot get called by onPress() method of TouchableHighlight

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, reactive-programming

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  PropTypes,
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Component
} = React;


var ResponsiveImage = require('react-native-responsive-image');
var styles = require('../../style');

class EventCard extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    nextPage: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='gray' onPress={() => {this.onclicked()}}>
        <View style={styles.global.card}>
          <ResponsiveImage source={require('../resources/images/card.png')} initWidth="130" initHeight="110" style={{padding:5}} />
          <Text style={styles.global.cardTitle}>{this.props.cardItem.title}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
  onclicked(){
    this.context.nextPage();
  }
}

module.exports = EventCard;
```

onclicked method cannot be called. what is mistake in my code? please suggest me. when i press Touchablehighlights no response is returned. nextPage() method is parent method which i had make static in parent class.

Comment: Hey.. I tried by removing 'ResponsiveImage' and onclick is getting called.. Mostly ResponsiveImage is consuming the click event.

Comment: oh man are you sure? wow ! i havenot tried  this. you really made my day man :)

Comment: Let me know if it worked

Comment: sorry man it didnot worked :( can you just show me your code please :)

Comment: There's nothing fundamentally wrong with your click event handler. I have tested it and it works.

Comment: but why didnot it work in my project? can you show me your code please :(

Comment: I gave an example of a very basic component in an answer.

Comment: Does it say anything in the chrome console? did you try putting a breakpoint in onClicked() ?

Comment: yes i have debugged in chrome and the click works, but i feels difficulty in calling static method of parent inside any child methods. can you suggest me something for that?

Comment: If you would like to call the method of a parent from within a child, the best way to do so would be to pass the method reference to the child as part of props.

Comment: cannot we do it by making static ?? i feels quite comfortable with it. since i am from java background. :)

Comment: I'm not completely sure of what you're asking. The variables and methods of parent components are not accessible to children unless explicitly passed to them. Scope does not apply here.

Comment: Ezra is right here. The simplest, and probably the best method for a child to access some method in its parent is to pass it through the props. I don't think that's much of a cognitive overhead either. 
on parent -> `<Child clickHandler={this.onClick} />`
on child -> `<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.onClick} > ...</...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to greatly modify your component, because I don't have the resources and other methods you're using as props and styles, but the concept is the same. I played around with it, just made a simple color change on press component for giggles. This component is imported into index.ios.js (or index.android.js in your case) like so: `import {EventCard} from './component';` where this component resides in component.js, and component.js and index.android.js reside in the same folder.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  PropTypes,
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

// I didn't bother installing dependencies.

// var ResponsiveImage = require('react-native-responsive-image');
// var styles = require('../../style');

export class EventCard extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    // nextPage: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  state = {
    color: 'black'
  }

  // This method takes the place of your onclicked method.
  changeColor = () => {
    let first = parseInt(Math.random() * 255);
    let second = parseInt(Math.random() * 255);
    let third = parseInt(Math.random() * 255);
    this.setState({
      color: 'rgba(' + first + ', ' + second + ', ' + third + ', 1)'
    });
  }
  render () {
    return(
      <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='gray'>
        <Second myColor={this.state.color} handlePress={this.changeColor} />
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}

class Second extends React.Component {
  setNativeProps = (props: Object) => {
    this._root.setNativeProps(nativeProps);
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <Text ref={component => this._root = component} style={{color: this.props.myColor}} onPress={this.props.handlePress}>
        Second.
      </Text>
    );
  }
}
// I don't have your resources or other dependencies.

// <View style={styles.global.card}>
//   <ResponsiveImage source={require('../resources/images/card.png')} initWidth="130" initHeight="110" style={{padding:5}} />
//   <Text style={styles.global.cardTitle}>{this.props.cardItem.title}</Text>
// </View>

// module.exports = EventCard;
```

Comment: yes you are right. How can we call static method of parent class inside any method of child components? In my above example as:      onclicked(){
       this.context.nextPage();
    }

Comment: If you would like to call the method of a parent from within a child, the best way to do so would be to pass the method reference to the child as part of props.

Comment: i have nested child components so i want to call method of first parent, so i have made it static like this:   static childContextTypes = {
      nextPage: React.PropTypes.func,
      closeDrawer: React.PropTypes.func
    };

     getChildContext() {
      return {
        nextPage: () => (this._nextPage),
        closeDrawer: () => (this._closeDrawer)
      };
    }

Comment: I've slightly refactored my code to demonstrate how to pass parent methods to child components.

Comment: setNativeProps = (props: Object) => {
    this.refs[COMMON_THREAD_ROW].setNativeProps(props);
  } what is this means bro??

Comment: Something I don't completely understand yet :p I encountered a bug, did some research, found a solution that worked. Read more about it here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html